# What does \. mean when matching in Perl? (backslash dot)

Tags: regex, perl, matching

I am wondering what the characters `\.` mean in Perl, specifically in a matching expression. I know the `\` can be an escape character. Is it simply escaping the dot? Or does it have an additional meaning together?

In the context below, I am assuming that when the condition `($ARGV[$i] =~ /\./)` is satisfied, the variable `$Chain` is *not* set to the argument `$ARGV[$i]`. I tried looking up information on Perl regular expressions and matching but I am having trouble fitting the context.

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#ARGV; $i++) {
    if ($ARGV[$i] && ! ($ARGV[$i] =~ /\./)) {
        $Chain .= " " .  $ARGV[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is addressed early in `perlre(1)` in the section that discusses V8 regex syntax. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Version-8-Regular-Expressions

Answer (score 8):

It's escaping the period so that it can match a period instead of using the period's usual special meaning.